# Behavior of UPDATE when your JOIN provides multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, update

Is this [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) defined to take the first row generated by `generate_series`? Or does it just happen to function like that.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo AS
SELECT 1 AS bar;

UPDATE foo
SET bar = t.x
FROM generate_series(15,1e3)
  AS t(x);
```

Or, should we be writing it like this...

```
UPDATE foo
SET bar = t.x
FROM ( SELECT * FROM generate_series(15,1e3) LIMIT 1 )
  AS t(x);
```

Answer (score -2):

From [the docs on `UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table. **When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.**
>
> Because of this indeterminacy, referencing other tables only within sub-selects is safer, though often harder to read and slower than using a join.

Comment: What is the point of adding an answer for what amounts to a direct quote from the documentation?  Add these details to your question.

Comment: What is the point of trolling all of my questions?

Comment: I'm not trolling you.  It's a legitimate question.

Comment: I didn't find it right away. I thought it was interesting when I did find it. You got any more legitimate questions?

Comment: The point of adding an *answer* is to actually provide an answer.  This does not do that, in my opinion.  It merely shows "guidance" that one should not rely on undocumented behavior.

Comment: Could you define *"provide an answer"* and *"guidance [with an answer]"*?

Comment: I don't find the answer useless .But it could certainly be improved. With some more explanation or an advice/example of what to do in the specific question.